# как применить одну функцию к нескольким классам js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Всем привет. Такой вопрос, как можно сделать три одинаковых круга(должны идти друг за другом), но при этом будет меняться только let content и let colorWord

```js
let circle = document.querySelector('.slide-page__circle');
let content = 'РазработкаРазработкаРазработкаРазработка';
let radius = 180;
let colorWord = ['#ccba96', '#161616', '#ccba96', '#161616']; //Цвета по количеству слов
let countWord = -1; //Счетчик слов
function generateLetters(text) {
  const letters = text.split('');
  const step = 360 / letters.length;
  letters.forEach((l, i) => {
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    changeColor(l, span);
    const deg = step * i;
    span.style.transform = transform(deg, radius);
    circle.append(span);
  })
}

function changeColor(l, span) {
  if (l.toUpperCase() === l) ++countWord; //Определяем новое слово по заглавной букве и увеличиваем счетчик слов
  span.innerText = l.toUpperCase(); //В css к верхнему регистру не приводим делаем это здесь
  span.style.color = colorWord[countWord]; //Присваиваем цвет
}

function transform(deg, radius = 180) {
  return `rotateY(${deg}deg) translateZ(${radius}px)`
}
generateLetters(content)
```

```css
.slide-page__content {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slide-page__scene {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  perspective-origin: 0 -150px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.slide-page__circle {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: rotate 35s linear infinite;
}

.slide-page__circle span {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 29px;
  background: #161616;
  color: white;
  font-size: 28px;
  perspective-origin: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.slide-page__circle span::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.45);
  transform: translateZ(-5px);
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(1turn);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-page__content">
  <div class="slide-page__scene">
    <div class="slide-page__circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let radius = 180;

function generateLetters(selector, text, colorWord) {
  const letters = text.split('');
  const step = 360 / letters.length;
  letters.forEach((l, i) => {
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    changeColor(l, span, colorWord);
    const deg = step * i;
    span.style.transform = transform(deg, radius);
    selector.append(span);
  });
}

function changeColor(l, span, colorWord) {
  span.innerText = l.toUpperCase(); //В css к верхнему регистру не приводим делаем это здесь
  span.style.color = colorWord; //Присваиваем цвет
}

function transform(deg, radius = 180) {
  return `rotateY(${deg}deg) translateZ(${radius}px)`;
}

let circle_1 = document.querySelector('.circle_1');
let content_1 = 'Разработка_1Разработка_1Разработка_1Разработка_1';
let color_1 = '#ccba96';
generateLetters(circle_1, content_1, color_1);

let circle_2 = document.querySelector('.circle_2');
let content_2 = 'Разработка_2Разработка_2Разработка_2Разработка_2';
let color_2 = 'green';
generateLetters(circle_2, content_2, color_2);

let circle_3 = document.querySelector('.circle_3');
let content_3 = 'Разработка_3Разработка_3Разработка_3Разработка_3';
let color_3 = '#ff0000';
generateLetters(circle_3, content_3, color_3);
```

```css
.slide-page__content {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slide-page__scene {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  perspective-origin: 0 -150px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.slide-page__circle {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: rotate 35s linear infinite;
}

.slide-page__circle span {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 29px;
  background: #161616;
  color: white;
  font-size: 28px;
  perspective-origin: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.slide-page__circle span::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.45);
  transform: translateZ(-5px);
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(1turn);
  }
}


/* Добавить стиль */

.slide-page__circle {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-page__content">
  <div class="slide-page__scene">
    <div class="slide-page__circle circle_1"></div>
    <div class="slide-page__circle circle_2"></div>
    <div class="slide-page__circle circle_3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```